# 1004 Unable to get the Workday_Intl property of Worksheet Function Class

Tags: excel, vba

Im at a loss at why I am getting the 1004 Runtime error with this code and could use some assistance.

Error happens here:

```
rescDate = Application.WorksheetFunction.WorkDay_Intl(CloseDate, 3, 11, Holidays)
```

Things ive tried:

```
Option Explicit
Dim CloseDate as Date

CloseDate = GeneralInfo.Range("genCloseDate")

rescDate = Application.WorksheetFunction.WorkDay_Intl(CloseDate, 3, 11, Holidays)
```

AND

```
Option Explicit

    Dim wb as workbook
    Dim CloseDate as Range

    Set wb=MLAChecklist 'Codename of workbook
    set CloseDate = wb.GeneralInfo.Range("genCloseDate")

    rescDate = Application.WorksheetFunction.WorkDay_Intl(CloseDate, 3, 11, Holidays)
```

When I step through the code, in either scenario I have tried the `CloseDate` variable does have the date in the format of MM/DD/YYYY.

Below is the full code as it stands right now:

```
    Option Explicit
    Sub FundDateCalc()
        Dim CloseDate As Range, HolidayDates As Range
        Dim rescDate As Date, FundingDate as Date
        Dim LoanPurp As String

        Set HolidayDates = Holidays.Range("Holidays")

        Set CloseDate = GeneralInfo.Range("genCloseDate")

        rescDate = Application.WorksheetFunction.WorkDay_Intl(CloseDate, 3, 11, Holidays)

        FundingDate = Application.WorksheetFunction.WorkDay(rescDate, 1, Holidays)

End Sub
```

Comment: What is `Holidays`? A worksheet? Shouldn't `HolidayDates` be passed to the worksheet functions instead?

Comment: Start by adding `Option Explicit` at the top of your code module, and fix any errors it flags up.

Comment: @MathieuGuindon - Correct Holidays is a worksheet Holidays is the codename for the worksheet.

Comment: So you're passing a `Worksheet` as an argument to the function - it's expecting a `Range`, I think ;-)

Comment: @TimWilliams I always add Option Explicit at the top of modules (I learned early on, from you actually, that is best practice).  The only error that pops up is the 1004 in regards to the `Workday_Intl` line.

Comment: Thats what it was @MathieuGuindon.  I knew it was something small.  Thanks :)  Now its off to (I think this goes to) CodeReview to get some help in turning this into an actual Function.